# C# - NetworkStream.Read - correct way to fill the entire buffer (or throw exceptions otherwise)

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

The [NetworkStream.Read method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) states that it returns zero on two cases:

- "If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0."
- "If the remote host shuts down the connection, and all available data has been received, the Read method completes immediately and return zero bytes."

And also there is the following observation:

> Check to see if the NetworkStream is readable by calling the CanRead property. If you attempt to read from a NetworkStream that is not readable, you will get an IOException.

I'm very confused about it. How do I know that I can keep reading or that I should stop trying to read?

Take the following sample method:

```
void Receive(byte[] buffer)
{
    int idx = 0;
    while (idx < buffer.Length)
    {
        if (input.CanRead)
        {
            int read = input.Read(buffer, idx, buffer.Length - idx);

            if (read == 0)
            {
                // ???
            }

            idx += read;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new MyLibConnectionClosedException("Cannot receive because the connection was closed");
        }
    }
}
```

It should fill the entire buffer or it should throw an exception (if the connection was closed or lost). What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely to me that MS would diverge from their standard practice of only returning "zero bytes read" *only* in the case that the end of stream has been reached. Can you specifically identify the document that states that zero is returned when "there is nothing to read now"? With all my experience with `System.IO.Stream` I'm calling this out as incorrect (if it isn't, I have a lot of fixing to do).

Comment: So `NetworkStream` derives from the abstract `Stream` class. Here the documentation is clear: returns: "The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached." I think any suggestion that 0 means anything other than "end of stream" is bad documentation.

Comment: The linked documentation says "If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0" (see link in the post, i'm updating my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an evidence based approach to establishing the facts... If you look at the source code for `Stream.CopyTo`, which relies on method [`Stream.InternalCopyTo`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,98ac7cf3acb04bb1) you'll see the following code for copying one stream to another:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int read;
while ((read = Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
```

This makes it absolutely clear to me that `0` represents the end of stream and not that "there is nothing to read now".

Any suggestion that a return value of `0` has a second meaning is incorrect, as this would make the implementation of `CopyTo` incorrect.

In short, to read a stream to the end, carry on reading until `Read` returns `0` (or an exception is thrown).

Comment: I updated my question, quoting the documentation. Maybe I misunderstood it?

Comment: @Eric.Void I think the documentation is confusing. I stand by my answer... The only case where `0` is returned is at the end of stream. The code for `CopyTo` makes this crystal clear. With regards to `CanRead`, this is used to indicate if it is legal to call `Read` (i.e. it's a readable stream). It has nothing to do with whether or not data is available, although for all types of stream, it will be set to `false` once the stream is disposed.

Comment: @Eric.Void In the case that the end of stream isn't reached, `Read` will block until it can make a read and return a non-zero value. I have ***a lot*** of code that relies upon this. It's worked flawlessly for many years.